# What is the neccesity of buttons?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and i just learned that if any view that is a subclass can be configured to respond to a touch input,then what purpose does a button serve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no sense, to me

Answer (score 1):

A button has proper style, for example the ripple effect when the user touches it.

You can style any view to work like a button, but if you need a button, the button view already have all the style necessary to work as a button.

Comment: I am not new to Android but your answer did not give any strong reasons why we use buttons rather than touch input

Comment: @InnerFire This question is rather ambiguous to begin with, but this is the most appropriate answer given. A `Button` is a `Button` because it looks and acts like a button. There's nothing more to be said.

Comment: @MikeM. I agree that this is the best answer till now but I wouldn't encourage too broad questions

Comment: @InnerFire Agreed. Questions which beg tautology, though, should be sorted at the root. That is, let's close the "question". Not sure why I started this argument in the first place. :-)

Comment: My first reaction was to flag the question too, but I though that this is a real question, so I answered in the best way to make clear that his question is right and there any other reason to use a Button instead of nothing reinventing the whell

Answer (score 0):

Button is a core element of Android design it has basic styling of a button you see in a html or swift app.

you can set left and right drawables button texts on press states many things easily without writing extra lines of codes.

I recommend you to read proper guide

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge it's all about UI, the buttons has special effects and characteristics that differs it from other views.

using the button simplifies the work on UI and saves a lot of code lines.